# How to solve this problem: $5^x = x^5$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $5^x = x^5$

I'm having trouble solving this problem. I tried taking log of both sides to get: $$x\log(5) = 5\log(x)$$ then $$x/\log(x)=5/\log(5)$$
But I'm not sure where to go from here. Am I in a wrong direction?

Comment: @Dovah-king, Is that the only solution?

Comment: @Dovah-king not for $x$ real; there is a solution between $1$ and $2$.

Comment: Yeah, i was thinking about a solution between $1$ and $2$. Is there an analytic method for solving this?

Comment: @Joffan, How do you know that there is a solution between 1 and 2?

Comment: I suggest using the fractions the other way up; the function $\frac {\ln x}x$ has a max at $e$

Comment: note that $2^4=4^2$, it needs to be outside that

Comment: @math why do we know there is a solution between $1$ and $2$?  because both $5^x$ and $x^5$ are continuous for positive $x$.  At $x=1$ you have $5^1>1^5$ meanwhile at $x=2$ you have $5^2<2^5$ (*as $25<32$*) so they must have crossed (*at least once*) on that interval as per the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 1):

The other real solution is $$-\frac{5}{\ln 5} W\left(-\frac{\ln 5}{5}\right)$$
where $W$ is the Lambert W function.

Comment: And Wolfy says this is about 1.76492.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

From the variations of the function $\dfrac{\ln x}x$, you can show there are two solutions: $x=5$, of course, and a solution between $1$ and $\mathrm e$.